# Where are InAPP purchases stored?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

This may be a silly question, but I haven't been able to find the answer. Where on the device should InApp purchases be stored? Are they downloaded to the bundle?

Comment: You can't modify your app bundle on the device while it's running, but you can (unintentionally) on the Simulator since it's using your computer's local filesystem, so be careful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to store them yourself. I'd use NSUserDefaults for simplicity.

They aren't saved to your app bundle, since that would invalidate the signature.

Comment: Also note that you can "restore" non-consumable purchases, which are saved on the app store, but you should only do this if the user requests it (the servers would get overloaded if you did it every launch).

Comment: Is `NSUserDefaults` available to the user for tinkering via iTunes?

Comment: @Yar: Not directly, but the user can always backup the device, edit the backup, and do a restore. Jailbreaking is also easy. There are various defenses (e.g. use a MAC) and various ways around that (e.g. copy "known good" settings from a device which has done the purchase). If faking a purchase does not *actually* harm anyone, it's not worth the effort to attempt to defend against; if not, iPhone DRM is trivial to bypass.

Comment: @ProudMember I meant Message Authentication Code. I assume, by "j/k", that your comment does not add anything to the discussion.

Answer (score 4):

I put up a pretty useful sample that includes saving your purchases to NSUserDefaults as tc said above.  I agree, that's the way to do it.

Let me know if you have any questions about the sample code.

[The App Tree - In App Purchase Sample - Free](http://www.theapptree.com/samples)